# Send specific data per node and gather results in MPI-Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I have trouble executing this program in mpi4py. My objective is to send specific data to a particular node (that is why I am not using scatter). After that, process the data in each node, and finally gather all the results.

Apparently, my program does not understand how to gather the data from different nodes (maybe because gather is designed to work with scatter). I tried to send the date with comm.send() and gather with comm.gather(). When I execute the program, it runs forever, and I don't see any result.

Can you help me to find out how to gather the data from the different nodes? Is there other function to do this? May I need a loop over the nodes?

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    data = list(np.arange(size) + 1)
    for i in range(size):
        comm.send(data[i], dest=i)
else:
    data = comm.recv(source=0)
    data += 1

print("rank", rank, "has data", data)

newData = comm.gather(data, root = 0)

if rank == 0:

    print("master collected", newData)
```

Comment: In my case, it does not run forever and I see results.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is blocking is that you are trying to send data from rank 0 to itself before the matching receive is posted. This is a deadlock. Now you could simply skip sending from rank 0 to itself - just copy the appropriate data. Or you could use non-blocking point to point communication (`isend` / `irecv`).

However, you shouldn't. The idiomatic approach is indeed to use `scatter`, and it works just fine, e.g.:

```
if rank == 0:
    full_data = list(np.arange(size) + 1)
else:
    full_data = None
data = comm.scatter(full_data)
```

Comment: generally speaking, you can use `MPI_IN_PLACE` on the root rank if it should not exchange data with itself.
that being said, i do not know if/how `mpi4py` handles that

Comment: I'm fairly sure you cannot use `MPI_IN_PLACE` with the lower-case pickling MPI functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Scatter.  It does exactly what you're trying to do.  See here for an illustration: http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/

Comment: *"You need to use Scatter [...] You cannot Gather without Scatter."* this is absolutely wrong. *"It does exactly what you're trying to do."* correct.

Comment: @Zulan: Thanks, I had my MPI terminology mixed up after using some other systems for a while. :)  Corrected the text now.

Comment: Thanks, guys! This clarifies me some stuff. But do you know how I can send elements one by one? My problem is that I do not want to load all the data and then send it to the nodes (the data is quite big, and it's larger than the memory). Ideally, I would like to load the data 1, send to a node. Then, load data 2, send to a node. And so on. Finally, gather all the results of the nodes. The examples than I have seen assume that you scatter the data all at once.@JohnZwinck, @Zulan

Comment: @code_jedi: Then it sounds like you want Send and not Scatter.  But really you should buy more RAM.

Comment: @code_jedi As I wrote in my answer, just skip send/receive for rank 0 to itself and use your code otherwise.